# Angular 15 form submitting issue

Tags: angular, typescript

this is my component file.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FirstStageQuery } from './first-stage-query.model'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-requester',
  templateUrl: './first-stage-query.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first-stage-query.component.css']
})
export class FirstStageQueryComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(NgForm) firststageform!: NgForm;
  firststage: FirstStageQuery = {
    contactno: '',
    subject: ''
  };

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {


  }

  saveFirstStage(firststageform: NgForm) {
    console.log(this.firststage);
  }


}
```

this is my model file

```
    export interface FirstStageQuery {
  contactno:string;
  subject:string;
  }
```

this is my html code

```
          <form name="form"  novalidate class="form-details" #firststageform="ngForm" 
      (ngSubmit)="firststageform.form.valid && saveFirstStage(firststageform)">
        <div class="container-fluid">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label  
                        class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-form-label form-label-custom">Subject<em>*</em></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                      <input type="text" name="subject" required [(ngModel)]="firststage.subject" class="form-control form-control-custom" placeholder="Subject"  />

                            <div *ngIf="subject.errors?.['required']">
                              Subject is required.
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email5" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-form-label form-label-custom">Annual Reporting Date
                         </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" name="contactno" [(ngModel)]="firststage.contactno" class="form-control form-control-custom"
                                placeholder="Contact No."  />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>     
      </form>
```

error said
Property 'subject' does not exist on type 'FirstStageQueryComponent'.

my approach is wrong or what is the reason for this error. I am very new to angular 15. so if you know any proper way to submit form, pls help. however i need to model driven approach,

Comment: The error is quite clear. There is no `subject` in the `FirstStageQueryComponent`.

Comment: how to rectify it

Comment: My bad from previous comment, which I remove my statement that is incorrect. For your reference: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-template-driven-forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this error happened because of this

```
<div *ngIf="subject.errors?.['required']">
                          Subject is required.
                        </div>
```

because you didn't define subject neither in you component and your template
in order to remove the error and your component work well you should do this

```
<input type="text" name="subject" required [(ngModel)]="firststage.subject" class="form-control form-control-custom" placeholder="Subject" #subject="ngModel" />

                        <div *ngIf="subject.errors?.['required']">
                          Subject is required.
                        </div>
                </div>
```

just add #subject="ngModel" to your input